# How to install NAOqi controller for simulated NAO robots in Webots

Tags: sdk, msys, nao-robot, webots

I was following this guide: https://github.com/omichel/naoqisim/blob/master/README.md

I installed msys64 and Vistual Studio. In msys I proceeded with the pacman commands as stated in the installation guide, which in turn donwloaded a bunch of stuff.

Now the next step in the Github guide proceeds with the Build.

I executed the commands:

```
$ WEBOTS_HOME='/c/Program Files/Webots'

$ cd /c/Users/Pawel/Desktop/NAOqi/naoqisim-master

$ make
```

After it finished downloading I got this:

```
simulator-sdk-2.1.4 100%[===================>] 379.16M   346KB/s    in 31m 31s

2019-02-07 23:11:10 (205 KB/s) - ‘simulator-sdk-2.1.4.1-win32-vs2010.zip’ saved [397574953/397574953]

# extracting simulator-sdk-2.1.4.1-win32-vs2010.zip
make[1]: unzip: Command not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile:63: simulator-sdk] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:7: default] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to install [unzip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unzip.htm).

Comment: I downloaded the unzip package, but the unzip command still can't be found.
Do I have to download the sources as well? Is there any other additional steps after the setup and installation?

Comment: You need to install unzip from the MSYS2 console by typing : "pacman -S unzip".

Comment: It seems the compilation of `naoqisim.exe` was successful. The error comes later and you can ignore it unless you need this opencv-based controller which is not needed by NAOqi.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is resolved. But for whoever else may have the same problem. I have had similar problem installing naoqi and stuff. This Github was actually quite helpful (and now it finally works on webots, i mean naoqi is found at least).

https://github.com/sunzhida/COMP4461_2017Fall_Lab4